# How to explode columns with multiple (dictionary like) json objects in each row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains some columns. The columns of interest have multiple json objects in a single row. it looks something like this:

```
IN: df=read_csv('filename.tsv',sep='\t')
IN: df

OUT: name RSN model version dt  si2 si3 pi1 wi20    wi28    li1 ci1 ai1 ai2 ai3 ad1 wi19    wi27    wan2    wan1    li3 li2 li5 li4 li7 li6 li9 li8 wi22    wi21    wi24    wi23    wi26    wi25    wi30    wi29    wi14    wi13    wi16    wi15    wi17    wi18
   0    DE1 RSN JCO4032 R2.15   12-03-21 06:53:32:155   14  46  831 5   149 2   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0   0   218419  553198  1754335 32208167    18594   28750   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN NaN NaN 
   1    DE1 RSN JCO4032 R2.15   12-03-21 06:54:04:343   14  46  863 5   149 2   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0   0   9063    209 99335   1941734 1084    1598    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN NaN NaN 
   2    DE1 RSN JCO4032 R2.15   12-03-21 07:04:07:579   13  46  1469    5   149 2   0   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0   0   152680  18355   1656295 29541773    17201   25804   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaN NaN NaN 

IN: df.wi17
OUT: 
    35                                                  NaN
    36                                                  NaN
    37    [{"mac":"2xx01:xxF","rssi":-60,"txrate...
    38    [{"mac":"20:4xx:1F","rssi":-60,"txrate...
    39                                                  NaN
Name: wi17, dtype: object

IN: df.wi17[37]
OUT: '[{"mac":"20:47xx:1F","rssi":-60,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":0,"rxbytes":0,"nxn":"1x1"},{"mac":"E8xx:A0","rssi":-57,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":1414810891,"rxbytes":808725830,"nxn":"1x1"}]'
```

I converted this column of *strings* and *NaNs* to a column of list of *dictionaries* using `json.loads`.

```
def parser2(d):
   if d!=d:
      return np.nan
   else:
      return json.loads(d)
df.wi17 = df.wi17.apply(parser2)
```

I am looking for a graceful solution to explode these dictionaries and group them on the basis of a unique *"mac"* which in turn be grouped by a unique *'RSN'* in the original *df*.

It should look something like this:

```
... RSN         .... mac        rssi  txrate  max_txrate  txbytes  rxbytes   nxn  ...
... RSNFDXXXKDF ... 2A:xxxx:sd   30   34      50          2323     34323     1x1  ...
... RSNFDXXXKDF ... 2A:xxxx:sd   50   84      70          20       2334343   1x1  ...
... RSNFDXXXKDF ... 3B:yyyy:sd   45   48      47          40       2334      2x2  ...
... RSNFDXXXKDF ... Nan         Nan   Nan     Nan         Nan      Nan       Nan  ...
... ADKNCCJXKDF ... AA:yyyy:sd   45   48      47          40       2334      2x2  ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`pd.Series()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series) on the data of column `wi17` and then [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
df2 = df.explode('wi17')
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.wi17), axis=1)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
```

Here, we use `df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.wi17), axis=1)` on `df2` which has been exploded with the list of dictionaries into a single dictionary in each row of `df2`.  Use the lambda function with pd.Series to expand a dictionary with its respective dictionary keys, values into column index and column values.

### Demo Run

**Test data construction**

```
data = {'name': ['DE1', 'DE2', 'DE3'], 'RSN': ['RSNJCO4032', 'RSNJCO4033', 'RSNJCO4034']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['wi17'] = ['[{"mac":"20:47xx:1F","rssi":-60,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":0,"rxbytes":0,"nxn":"1x1"},{"mac":"E8xx:A0","rssi":-57,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":1414810891,"rxbytes":808725830,"nxn":"1x1"}]', '[{"mac":"40:17xx:1F","rssi":-62,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":0,"rxbytes":0,"nxn":"1x1"},{"mac":"F8xx:B0","rssi":-58,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":1414810891,"rxbytes":808725830,"nxn":"1x1"}]', '[{"mac":"60:07xx:1F","rssi":-64,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":0,"rxbytes":0,"nxn":"1x1"},{"mac":"A8xx:C0","rssi":-61,"txrate":72.0,"max_txrate":72.0,"txbytes":1414810891,"rxbytes":808725830,"nxn":"1x1"}]']

import json
def parser2(d):
   if d!=d:
      return np.nan
   else:
      return json.loads(d)
df.wi17 = df.wi17.apply(parser2)

print(df)

  name         RSN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                wi17
0  DE1  RSNJCO4032  [{'mac': '20:47xx:1F', 'rssi': -60, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 0, 'rxbytes': 0, 'nxn': '1x1'}, {'mac': 'E8xx:A0', 'rssi': -57, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 1414810891, 'rxbytes': 808725830, 'nxn': '1x1'}]
1  DE2  RSNJCO4033  [{'mac': '40:17xx:1F', 'rssi': -62, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 0, 'rxbytes': 0, 'nxn': '1x1'}, {'mac': 'F8xx:B0', 'rssi': -58, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 1414810891, 'rxbytes': 808725830, 'nxn': '1x1'}]
2  DE3  RSNJCO4034  [{'mac': '60:07xx:1F', 'rssi': -64, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 0, 'rxbytes': 0, 'nxn': '1x1'}, {'mac': 'A8xx:C0', 'rssi': -61, 'txrate': 72.0, 'max_txrate': 72.0, 'txbytes': 1414810891, 'rxbytes': 808725830, 'nxn': '1x1'}]
```

**Run New Codes**

```
df2 = df.explode('wi17')
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.wi17), axis=1)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  name         RSN         mac  rssi  txrate  max_txrate     txbytes    rxbytes  nxn
0  DE1  RSNJCO4032  20:47xx:1F   -60    72.0        72.0           0          0  1x1
1  DE1  RSNJCO4032     E8xx:A0   -57    72.0        72.0  1414810891  808725830  1x1
2  DE2  RSNJCO4033  40:17xx:1F   -62    72.0        72.0           0          0  1x1
3  DE2  RSNJCO4033     F8xx:B0   -58    72.0        72.0  1414810891  808725830  1x1
4  DE3  RSNJCO4034  60:07xx:1F   -64    72.0        72.0           0          0  1x1
5  DE3  RSNJCO4034     A8xx:C0   -61    72.0        72.0  1414810891  808725830  1x1
```

### Edit

For better system performance (execution time), you can try to change the `.apply()` function to `list(map(...)` as follows:

```
df2 = df.explode('wi17')
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.Series, df2['wi17'])), index=df2.index)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
```

### Edit 2

The system performance (execution time) is further fine-tuned.  Benchmarking shows more than **20x times faster** execution time can be achieved with using [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to expand the json structure into a new Pandas DataFrame for merging into the original DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.explode('wi17')
df2['wi17'] = df2['wi17'].fillna({i: {} for i in df2.index})  # as suggested by @TwerkingPanda to handle NaN entries. 
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True), 
                 pd.json_normalize(df2['wi17'])],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Benchmarking system performance with 30,000 rows** (each row with 2 json, hence total 60,000 json)

```
df1 = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df1.explode('wi17')
```

---

**(1) Benchmark for original version using `.apply()` with `pd.Series()`**

```
%%timeit
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.wi17), axis=1)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
21.9 s ± 82.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**(2) Benchmark for revised version using `list(map(...))` with `pd.Series()` and `pd.DataFrame()`:**

```
%%timeit
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.Series, df2['wi17'])), index=df2.index)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
20.6 s ± 364 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**(3) Benchmark for revised version using `pd.json_normalize()`:**

```
%%timeit
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True), 
                 pd.json_normalize(df2['wi17'])],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
999 ms ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Edt 3

This version further improves on system performance (execution time) and at the same time allows keeping the original series index for OP to ensure the data integrity.

As the json objects are in one level without nesting, we can make use of the more efficient DataFrame constructor `pd.DataFrame()` to expand the json fields into columns, as follows:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 pd.DataFrame(df2['wi17'].to_list(), index=df2.index)],
                 axis=1)
```

**Benchmark for version using `pd.DataFrame()`:**

```
%%timeit
df3 = pd.concat([df2.drop('wi17', axis=1), 
                 pd.DataFrame(df2['wi17'].to_list(), index=df2.index)],
                 axis=1)
116 ms ± 483 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This version is further improved by more than **8x times faster** than the version using `pd.json_normalize()` and more than **180x times faster** than the version using `df.apply()` + `pd.Series()`.   Moreover, we have the flexibility to retain the index the original dataframe on the expanded columns by using the `index=` parameter of `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, this method works and gets to the desired result, but is awfully slow. Even loops over nparrays are exponentially faster and for medium to large datasets, it is highly impractical since it took 2.5 hours for a 100 MB csv file.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda  Please see my edit for a version with better system performance.  Let me know whether it fits your time requirement.

Comment: @SeanBean list(map(...) : the output of this method is a single column (0) with each row containing an array like series. This output is not very different from the raw 'wi17' column.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda  To show dictionary keys as column index please remove the `np.array` enclosing list(map(...) then.   I tested versions with and without np.array() and found with np.array() can further improve the execution time, but overlooked that it cannot retain the expanded column index.  Using list(map(...) is around 30% faster with while with np.array improve to 50% faster.   You can consider manually changing the column index after the main processing if that can save you execution time.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda Please find enhanced version fine-tuned to more than 20x times faster with 60,000 json.  Hope this can cater for your performance need.

Comment: @SeanBean. The `json_normalize`  is indeed way more fast. suggest adding either a `df2['wi17'].fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})` inside it or replacing the NaNs while parsing to deal with float value error in `json_normalize()` since it cannot handle NaN exceptions. Although I verified it and it looks okay but since json_normalize does not keep the original series index, can you verify if the index of pre operated df matches the final df? since another column has timestamps and they must match.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda The index of the pre operated df should match with the index of output from json_normalize because they both stem from the same df2 that has been exploded with the original columns including both RSN and wi17 columns AND also that json_normalize just normalizes JSON data into a flat table without reshuffling the data.   I think a major constraint of your use case is of the big data size.  Otherwise, the initial version using apply() should handle it nicely including propagating and retaining original index.

Comment: Here, the index is not retained because we have to reset the index for the original df (the df2.drop(...) part) in order for it to be able to concat with the output of json_normalize.  If we don't do this, another option maybe to merge the 2 pieces, but it would run slower for merge and the output of json_normalize does not contain common fields to merge with the original piece.  In this case, seems like execution time is the most important but it also limits our choice of feasible solutions.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda  Added your suggested edit of fillna    Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @TwerkingPanda See my newest Edit 3 which provides solution to further improve on the execution time (by more than 8x times faster) and at the same time can retain the row index of original dataframe.  Let me know if you would like to test it.

Comment: Tested it. Sped up the execution by 5x for the data I was processing today. thanks again. pd.json_normalize() also retained the index when fillna was used inside though.